# Which logging system does Kali Linux use?

Tags: kali-linux, logs

**Greetings**

I have recently switched to Linux due to my passion for software engineering and CyberSecurity, the Linux distribution is [**`Kali`**](https://www.kali.org/) version:

`[This info is confidential.] 6.5.0-kali3-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.5.6-1kali1 (2023-10-09) x86_64 GNU/Linux`

I'm trying to learn the fundamentals at the moment, that is why I am mainly focused on the logging system.
I understand that all [**`Debian`**](https://www.debian.org/) operating systems use the [**`rsyslog daemon`**](https://www.rsyslog.com/) for handling the loggings, and although there are resources mentioning that Kali uses the same logging daemon as Debian:

**But actually trying to manipulate the service does not return a valid answer:**

```
┌──([This info is confidental])-[~]
└─$ service rsyslog start
Failed to start rsyslog.service: Unit rsyslog.service not found.
```

**and also searching for the log files stored by the daemon does not give back any useful information:**

```
┌──([This info is confidential])-[~]
└─$ locate rsyslog
/usr/share/metasploit-framework/modules/auxiliary/dos/syslog/rsyslog_long_tag.rb
```

Altough the [**`Metasploit penetration testing framework`**](https://www.metasploit.com/) uses this naming convention, no other logging files could be found.

## Question N.1:

> Am I doing something wrong/there is something wrong with my operating system version, or Kali Linux uses other branches of logging daemons?

## Question N.2:

> Is there any commands for finding the name of the logging daemon?

Comment: "_I'm trying to learn the fundamentals at the moment_" - despite your passion for cybersecurity I would urge you not to try and learn the fundamentals with Kali. Take a note general distribution that behaves properly and as would be expected, and when you're ready install the pentesting tools, etc. ok that. Or later move to Kali - but don't start with it

Comment: @ChrisDavies Too late unfortunately, I shooted myself in the foot learning the other concepts, but I don't regret it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP should not be using Kali

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I understand that all Debian operating systems use the rsyslog daemon for handling the loggings, and although there are resources mentioning that Kali uses the same logging daemon as Debian:

Your information seems to be somewhat outdated. Since the introduction of `systemd` to Debian, the situation has changed: now in Debian 12, `systemd-journald` is the default logging daemon, and `rsyslog` is an optional package that might be used if you want to accept incoming logs from remote sources, or need other `rsyslog` features.

> Am I doing something wrong/there is something wrong with my operating system version, or Kali Linux uses other branches of logging daemons?

Yes. You should learn about `systemd-journald` and its `journalctl` command.

For example, run `journalctl -u systemd-journald` to see what it has logged about itself.

> Is there any commands for finding the name of the logging daemon?

Yes. In any modern Linux distribution that uses `systemd`,

```
systemctl list-units --type=service
```

would be a good place to start.

But as a cybersecurity enthusiast, why haven't you already run `ps axf` and taken the time to figure out the purpose of every process you see on your system, at least at the basic level: is it a kernel process? A system service? Or is it part of your own login session?